# Website works in Google Chrome but not Internet Explorer

Tags: html, security, firefox, google-chrome

I've checked a few places for an answer but I could not find one, so I thought I'd ask. I created a website on a free HTML5 template (the template was for a photo gallery). The website works fine on Google Chrome and Firefox but for some reason, some stuff like the fonts dont appear in Internet Explorer (tried with and without compatibility settings on IE9). Could this be because of IE's security measures or have I coded it incorrectly?

The website is at [masidtech.com](http://www.masidtech.com)

On Chrome it looks like

[image: http://masidtech.com/working.jpg]

But on Internet Explorer it looks like

[image]

I was going to use paste bin but the pastes look really ugly for source code.

So I have uploaded the entire website to MediaFire at http://www.mediafire.com/?9m2108pgzyje79t
and it's a 7Zip file (or I guess you could view source)

+I am no coding guru so I'd really appreciate if you could throw in some layman and thanks.

Comment: Why not? This seems a perfectly reasonable question, and the person asking has provided the problem, the code, and has explained that this is their last port of call.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues in recent past. I can help you if you provide certain details. I just checked the link with the working image. I also tested the link with the notworking.jpg

Can you tell me the exact url in the browser which u see after http://masidtech.com/ 
for the non working image.

This is not a big issue, with modern browser in scene, and due to their hefty security policies the same website behaves differently in different browsers.

Comment: thanks, when I open up Internet Explorer, and navigate to http://masidtech.com/ , the address does not change. it remains the same and IE renders the webpage incorrrectly

Comment: Hey, I checked this in the compatibility view and it seems all good. It is working perfectly fine in IE 9 compatibility view. I believe it is some JS issue which is not making it apt when the compatibility view is disabled.

Comment: thanks, i cant believe i missed the compatibility view! i guess i have a choice of instructing my traffic to click the compatibility button or rewrite the website. thanks for your help!

Comment: well the issue is yet not sorted. It is not considered as a good customer experience if you ask your customer to switch to compatibility mode to rewrite the website. What I would suggest is to use the following: Pro grammatically switch customer's browser to Compatibility mode.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819026/how-to-turn-on-ie9-compatibility-view-programmatically-in-javascript

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what i was hunting around for- my website to force compatibility, however Rich below says it's a bad idea altogether...hmm...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cufon doesn't work in IE9 – a friend has had a similar issue this week. I'm not sure why, or if there is a way to get cufon to work, as I haven't used it.

There are two options - keep using Cufon (why? I don't really get why Cufon exists!), and add this above your first replace() call:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Cufon.set('engine', 'canvas');
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Alternatively, and prefered, use font-face. If you use a eot, ttf and woff version of your font, it will work everywhere. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator has a tool to generate the fonts and the code from a ttf, if the font allows it.

You may find that http://www.google.com/webfonts has the font needed instead, which is Google's way of hosting fonts.

Edit: I've had a look and found Google has it: http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Quicksand . Follow the wizard, stick their one line of code in your `<head>`, remove cufon and it will work.

Nice site design by the way :)

Comment: thanks for the help, will try this, could someone clarify why radashk RADU says I shouldnt do this here? i mean is this like a hardcore coding forum?, again thanks a lot, will see if the webfonts work!

Comment: We get a lot of people asking really basic questions about IE, along the lines of "this is my first site. Why doesn't it work in IE" with no extra info. Ignore radashk RADU - he's been here 8 months and accrued 175 reputation. I've been here 3 years and 8 months and have 18k reputation, and I think it's a perfectly fine question!

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't use the compat view in IE – you'll find it hurts more than it saves. I can't see any reason to use Cufon, unless the font is not allowed to be embedded. I've never used compat mode on any site I've ever made.

Comment: Also, just found some code that will make Cufon work in IE9. I'd still drop using it though.

Comment: thats what i was wondering, it would be a bad idea to force compatibility view for explorer with <meta> or something else, so yeah, i will try a different webfont, or if that dosent work, darn websafe fonts i guess...

Comment: Font-face works well, it's been in IE since v5.5, so it's well tested. I mean, if you have to use compat mode then do, but you'll likely find other problems as you keep working on it.

Comment: this is weird, with the google webfonts, i added the line in and got rid of cufon, but the new font only renders the menu at the bottom. the title dissppears and is in the wrong font...hmm..